# Behringer C-1 Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone

I'm extremely new to Ubuntu so I thought perhaps I would get the necessary help here.

I purchased a Behringer C-1 microphone to record audio via my computer however microphone doesn't record at the moment. It is not recognised by computer either. So I was told to download the drivers for it which were supposedly on behringer website. The issue is they don't show the drivers to download anymore on the website. Then I searched online to see if I can find the drivers there. But all I can find is file downloads for windows.

Is there any other way I can do this on Ubuntu? I simply need to download the drivers.